places far away from each other but similar every now and then
What (approximately) is common to Paris, mid Mongolia and mid North Washington state border with Canada, and when was it manifested last time recently? Also, in what (approximately) do these places differ then when manifested?
hint 1

 added seasonal tag, and then time tag, as incremental help

hint 2

 latitude and longitude (and tags)


All three of them (approximately) are rot13(ylvat ba gur sbegl avagu cnenyyry) but I don't see how that could have been manifested recently....

@Avastar rot13(nal vqrn nobhg jung fbzrgvzrf vf fcrpvny nobhg sbegl avagu cnenyyry gb ortva jvgu)

These places

have no (completely dark) night in late June around the summer solstice (e.g., Paris).


What these locations share is the experience of a total solar eclipse within the past decade, though the specifics of each eclipse differed.
Paris, France: Experienced a partial solar eclipse on March 20, 2015.
Mid Mongolia: Experienced a total solar eclipse on August 1, 2008.
Mid North Washington State border with Canada: Experienced a total solar eclipse on August 21, 2017.
